# R: How to use a function argument as part of a variable name

Tags: r, string, function, variables

I want to use a function to return something that contains the argument value as part of its variable name.

For instance, as a simple example:

```
a <- 'file1'

fun <- function(a) {
a.df <- read.table(file=a)
return(a.df)
}
```

But how do I create the variable name of a.df? so in this example, I would like to return a data frame file1.df

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you'd like to have an object named `file1.df`?

Comment: Don't do this. You almost certainly don't need to. You've probably got a list of file names and think you want to create a number of data frames, but you don't, that's a bad thing. Create a *list* of data frames. Lots of Qs here that show how to do that. Constructing things with assign and then placing them in the global env is usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
a <- 'file1'
fun <- function(x)
{
  assign(paste0(x, ".df"), "I am in global environment!", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
fun(a)
file1.df
[1] "I am in global environment!"
```

There are several similar examples in `?assign`, check these as well. Note that functions that modify variables in global environment (this is called a *side-effect*) are in some cases considered as a doubtful practice, though in your case I suppose this is justified.